# How to set the jquery draggable with margin left?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

On body load `scale_roll` div normally drag the full area of the `main_scale` div in x-axis. 
Then while clicking `click` function, the  `scale_roll` div shall be move by margin-left css style.
Then drag the `scale_roll`, only drag the balance div tag, not able to drag full div tag (before 100px).
The `margin-left` property makes the problem in drag? How to drag the divtag in full area with marginleft?   [JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4skeuhu3/1/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the `marginLeft` to `left` css

**JS:**

```
$('#click').click(function(){
    $(".scale_roll").css("left",'100px');
});
```

<kbd>**[RESULT](http://jsfiddle.net/sheshu036/4skeuhu3/2/)**</kbd>

Comment: This kind of problem was rises in my other script see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30935873/when-calling-raphael-function-jquerys-draggable-and-resizable-not-working this.